# REST Django - filter with multiple variables

Tags: django, api, rest

I know you can do something like :

```
if Test.objects.filter(id = 2).exists():
    #do something
```

But with my attempt of using two variables, it does not work properly. I have a table with two Foreign keys to a User and a Project. I want to see if a specific combination exists.
This attempt is what I tried but does not work.

```
if Test.objects.filter(user = User, project = Project).exists():
    #do something
```

Maybe I just implemented it wrong ?
my whole line is this. I get username and projectid by POST in the request.data

```
if Userproject.objects.filter(user= User.objects.get(username = request.data.get('username',0), project = Project.objects.get(id = request.data.get('projectid',0)).exists():
```

Comment: What are the errors you are running into?

Comment: I'm really new to this so I have no clue how to debug a not working view
Edit: found out its indeed a syntax Error in the line i posted

Comment: @Nic0lodeon: the brackets are not balanced. You should close two parenthesis at `.get('username',0))`, not one.